Configuration Matrix parameters of Kalman Filter opencv c++
I'm trying to use the kalman filter implemented in opencv (c++) and I don't understand how the vary matrix parameters are implemented.
In the example provided on opencv the various settings are made
    randn(state, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(0.1));
    KF.transitionMatrix = (Mat_<float>(2, 2) << 1, 1, 0, 1);
    setIdentity(KF.measurementMatrix);
    setIdentity(KF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-5));
    setIdentity(KF.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-1));
    setIdentity(KF.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(1));
    randn(KF.statePost, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(0.1));

The completely code is here https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/de/d70/samples_2cpp_2kalman_8cpp-example.html
Actually I'm able to understand just the transition matrix, but the other?
My goal is to implement a kalman filter that predicts the future point.
Specifically, I have a video of a moving car being occluded for a certain period of time and I need to identify the position it will be in after this time.
Any advice is welcome, I thank you in advance for your availability.

This is not a development question but its related to mathematical and physical properties of the problem you are trying to handle with the KF (statistics of measurement noise, of model noise and so on) and it's often tricky to set properly.
